# как заставить двигаться квадратик сразу, я делал через SetTimeout рекурсией, но не выходит по нормальному

Tags: javascript, html

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var SNAKE = $('#SNAKE');
  var BODY = $('body');

  BODY.keydown(function(e) {
    var key = e.keycode || e.which;
    if (key == 38) {
      drop('TOP');
    }

    if (key == 39) {
      drop('RIGHT');
    }

    if (key == 40) {
      drop('BOTTOM');
    }

    if (key == 37) {
      drop('LEFT');
    }


  });
  function drop(vector) {
    var step = 25;
    var snakePosTop = parseInt(SNAKE.css('top'));
    var snakePosLeft = parseInt(SNAKE.css('left'));
    var MAX_TOP = 25;
    var MAX_RIGHT = 450;
    var MAX_BOTTOM = 450;
    var MAX_LEFT = 25;
    switch (vector) {
      case 'TOP':
        if (!(snakePosTop  < MAX_TOP)) {
          var snakePosTop = snakePosTop - step;
          SNAKE.css('top', snakePosTop + 'px')
        }
        break;
      case 'RIGHT':
        if (!(snakePosLeft  > MAX_RIGHT)) {
              var snakePosLeft = snakePosLeft + step;
              SNAKE.css('left', snakePosLeft + 'px')
        }
        break;
      case 'BOTTOM':
        if (!(snakePosTop  > MAX_BOTTOM)) {
          var snakePosTop = snakePosTop + step;
          SNAKE.css('top', snakePosTop + 'px');
        }
        break;
      case 'LEFT':
        if (!(snakePosLeft  < MAX_LEFT)) {
          var snakePosLeft = snakePosLeft - step;
          SNAKE.css('left', snakePosLeft + 'px')
        }
        break;

    }
    // var timerId = setTimeout(function() {
    //
    //   drop(vector);
    // }, 500);
      }

  // clearTimeout(timerId);
  //    if (key == 37 || key == 38  || key == 39) {
  // console.log(key);

});
```

```css
.Field {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background: #fff;
  border: 2px solid red;
  margin: 10% auto;
  position: relative;
}

.SNAKE {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  left: 225px;
  top: 450px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="Field" id="Field">
  <div class="SNAKE" id="SNAKE"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: В чем проблема? Квадратик вроде двигается нормально

Comment: @ДмитрийМатвиенко, вроде автор хочет написать змейку, соответственно нужно чтобы через заданный интервал времени квадратик смещался, а при нажатии стрелок на клавиатуре изменялось направление движения

Comment: соврешенно верно, пробовал через setTimeout рекурсией  только проблема в том, что если я двигаюсь вверх и нажму вниз, то квадратик будет двигаться вверх и вниз, то есть значение вверх не отменяется